# How to discord authentication in expo-auth-session?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, discord, expo

I'm new to expo and I trying expo-auth-session for discord but return "validation error auth url must be a valid uri"

This is my code

```
const { authorize, clientId, scopes } = discord;
const useProxy = true;
const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({ useProxy });

export default function Login() {
    const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(authorize);
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId,
            redirectUri,
            scopes,
        },
        discovery
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(response)
    }, [response]);

    const onLogin = async () => {
        promptAsync({useProxy}).catch(e =>{
          console.log(e);
        })
    };

    return (
        <View>
         <Button title="Login" disabled={!request} onPress={onLogin} />
        </View>
    );
}
```